# What will the most correct microdata schema be for a store listing brands?

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

I have a store page listing what fashion brands they are selling. But I'm not sure what microdata schema to use. I'm using the schema from [schema.org](http://schema.org).

Basically the list looks like this:

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Store">
 // Store info here

 <ul id="brandList">
  <li id="7750">
    <div class="brandInfo">
      <a href="http://...">Celine Engelstad</a>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img title="Celine Engelstad" src="http://..." class="logo">
    </div>
  </li>
  // More items here
 </ul>
</span>
```

Would this be the correct schematic to use?

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Store">
 // Store info here

 <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
   <ul id="brandList">
    <li itemprop="productID" id="7750">
      <div itemprop="manufacturer" class="brandInfo">
        <a itemprop="url" href="http://...">Celine Engelstad</a>
      </div>
      <div itemprop="logo" class="logo">
        <img itemprop="logo" title="Celine Engelstad" src="http://..." class="logo">
      </div>
    </li>
    // More items here
  </ul>
</span>
```

1) Since it's not a list of products, rather a list of brands, is it correct to use `http://schema.org/Product`
2) Brand name is both a name and link. Can I use nested `itemprop` as I have done?
3) Is there any point in using `itemprop="productID"` as this is not an item for purchase, buth the ID of the brand on my site?

---

**Update 17.07.2013**

I've implemented the following structure to stores listing brands after some outside help:

```
<ul class="brand-list>
  <li id="426">
    <span itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemscope="">
      <div class="brandInfo floatLef" itemprop="name">
        <a href="#" class="" itemprop="url">American Retro</a>
      </div>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Would this be correct to use e.g. on the front page for a section called **most popular brands** as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brand is an ORGANIZATION, not a product, therefore is not covered by the realm of a product schema.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the kind of stores you intend to list;  for brick & mortar locations, use the [store microdata schema](http://schema.org/Store); if, on the other hand, what you are listing are brands you sell on your own store, you'd probably be better off with the [brand schema](http://schema.org/Brand) instead.